# Angular UI Tabs, justified to false in mobile

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-ui

Im using Angular UI Tabs component with the **attr justified="true".**
this works ok in desktop, but when resolution change for tablets and phones, I want to **set justified to false.**

I dont want to use **@media-queries** to "force" the default **.nav-justified** class, just to render properly.

```
  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your css should do it :

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
display: table-cell !important;
width: 1% !important;
}
```

This is more of a css hack than angular related but well ..

Comment: yeah, but that kind of hacks, its what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Basically the default behavior ok bootstrap makes sense (on small screens, justified horizontal tabs are not really good).

The "clean" way to do this would be to somehow fork bootstrap because you want it to be non-responsive on tabs.

Also, overriding bootstrap is not that bad. It is quite a common practice.

Comment: You are right about the behavior in mobile, but the project designer does not want to use it in that way. 
Actually I'm modifing Angular UI tabs component to get this result.